# OSX CPU/Mem monitor application/widget

Tags: macos, cpu-usage

I knew someone that had a some app running at the botton left of his screen near he's dock, which monitored cpu usage at least. It had to green bars, prob one for each core.

**I'm wondering if anyone knows what app that is or of a free app that is like it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a native app: Activity Monitor.

To show stats on Dock, go to `View -> Dock Icon` and select what you want to display.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few tools availible:

- **Built-in**: Activity Monitor: included with OS X, availible at `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`
- **Paid or free:** The 'iStat' applications and widgets by [iSlayer](http://www.islayer.com/apps/). I use iStat Menus to monitor RAM usage without hogging precious, precious windowable space.
- **Free**: [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/) is a more advanced tool that will run shell scripts and return the results on your desktop. You can style it in various ways to [produce some really stunning effects](http://nicinabox.com/projects/geektool-scripts/), if you're looking for eye candy.
- **Paid**: [Stattoo](http://www.panic.com/stattoo/) by Panic. This is old, and not free.